# ¿Qué quiere decir "UNKNOWN FRANGMENTS " en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Este es mi xml estoy trabajando con Google maps no se que hacer no me funciona, obtengo el mensaje :

> Unknown fragments

Este es mi layout:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etOrigin"
    android:hint="Enter origin address" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter destination address"
    android:id="@+id/etDestination" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find path"
        android:id="@+id/btnFindPath" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_distance"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 km"
        android:id="@+id/tvDistance" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clock"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 min"
        android:id="@+id/tvDuration" />
</LinearLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: y tu class como esta de la actividad

Answer (score 0):

En tu layout estas usando un Fragmento de la clase `SupportMapFragment`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

tu proyecto seguramente no tiene las dependencias necesarias para usarlo, por esa razón se muestra el mensaje "`Unknown fragments`".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que sea reconocido este tipo de `Fragment`,  agrega la dependencia en tu archivo `build.gradle` y sincroniza tu proyecto con los archivos gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
}
```

Comment: grasias solo que ahora me da error ahi mismo pero en esta parte  """compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'""

Comment: uff tienes una versión antigua de la library de soporte, cambia por: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

Comment: jje si solo que uff este proyecto me esta dando dolor de cabeza se arregla algo y se desordena otro